# Connection Manager issue to shared file location from SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run the package from a SQL Server and pick up excel file from a common fileshare location. I get the following error-

> "Package:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: ""Microsoft Access Database Engine""  Hresult: 0x80004005 
>   Description: ""The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or
>   write to the file  '*File Share location*'. It is already opened
>   exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write
>   its data."".

I have confirmed that the file isnt open on the server on which the package is running from. 
Any help regarding this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, it turns out the other workstation was working on the file and not in 'read only' mode. the workstation has an ODBC excel file DSN setup.

If this is your case, you need got to the workstation's DSN setup , and make sure the 'read only' option is enabled.